# Is there any way to access my btc without my bitcoin core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I recently bought some bitcoins and got them transferred to my bitcoin core wallet. My fault is that I did not do any research on bitcoin core and found out that it synchronizes with the bitcoin network first before you can actually use your wallet. The synchronization is taking a lot of time. Is there any other way I can access my coins? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'd have to parse the `.bitcoin/wallet.dat` file (possibly using a script like [this python script](https://gist.github.com/msm595/7595164)) to recover the private keys, convert them to a WIF ([Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format)) and find another application that will let you import private keys. You might be better off just waiting for it to sync.